# What statistical tests use resampling?

Tags: nonparametric, bootstrap, resampling

I have heard, that resampling techniques like bootstrapping are part of how many non-parametric statistical tests were developed/derived, but after going through the maths behind a few I have seen little evidence of this.

What tests use resampling? or were developed or derived from ideas about resampling?

Comment: permutation tests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resampling methods like bootstrap and permutation tests give ways to make nonparametric tests. You can make them for all manner of situations. But they're not typically *named* tests, since you make a test to your specifications at the time you need it.

For example, if you want a permutation test of a difference in means, that's exactly what you do. If you instead want a permutation test of a Pearson correlation (with an uncorrelated null, at least), you do that instead. If you want to do a bootstrap test of a coefficient in some complicated model, you can do that.

On the other hand, many of the non-parametric tests you would see in a basic stats course (rank based tests like a Wilcoxon signed rank test or a test of a Spearman correlation) are a subset of permutation tests where the test statistic is based on ranks, rather than on the original data values. These tests do have names, largely because (for continuous distributions at least) by taking ranks you fix the values used in computation of the test statistic across all samples of that size, so you can work out the distribution under the null for any sample from a continuous distribution and so produce a table for the test. Given permutation tests were developed before computers, this made permutation tests on rank-transformed data particularly attractive. Outside of rank-based tests permutation tests were usually practical mainly in quite small samples before there were computers.

For resampling tests that resample the actual data - or sometimes related quantities like residuals - (pretty much all bootstrap tests and permutation tests other than those based on ranks) you can't produce tables since the rejection region for the test depends on the particular sample values you observe.

With widely available inexpensive computers (especially from the 80s onward), this restriction to using ranks or very small samples was no longer the case - permutation tests performed directly on the data became much more practical, even in large samples (particularly since it's not necessary to obtain every permutation, we can simply sample from the permutations using random sampling).

Similarly with bootstrap tests; they became practical once computers were widely available to carry out the resampling of the data.

Comment: Would Kruskal–Wallis,Mann Whitney U and Dunns tests be other examples?

Comment: Certainly the first two. Dunn's test is a post hoc test and one that I've only seen done using an asymptotic approximation, but it could be done using an actual permutation distribution of ranks.

Comment: I read through the derivations of the tests, and I still don't get it, why is ranking the data a kind of sub sampling?

Comment: It isn't. If you do all possible permutations of the ranks and compute the test statistic, you can get the null distribution of the rank based test. You can do this without seeing the data.